# Transform to Normal...or is there a better distribution for this case?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation, interpretation, standard-deviation

I'm not sure whether the right approach here is to transform to Normal or if there's another distribution that perfectly fits the data. What I'm trying to analyze is payroll data each pay period for a commissioned set of employees with identical job descriptions and commission rate. If they choose to take on no work during a pay period, their minimum pay would be 0.00. (However, I am inclined to exclude such individuals from the population as what I'm really interested in is the spread for pay > 0.00 as that implies the individual does want to work. This said, the minimum possible value is nonetheless 0.00; i.e., this isn't draw-against-commission where there could be negative values.)

When I analyze the current 8/1-8/15 data set for the 17 employees who meet that test, I get a mean of 808.88 and a Standard Deviation of 536.51. Thus the range from -1 to +1 SD is 272.37 to 1,345.39; -2 to +2 is -264.14 to 1,881.89; and -3 to +3 is -800.64 to 2,418.40.

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this correctly, but I'm making the deduction that because I'm getting negative values (which are impossible in practice), the standard deviation is "wrong" for this dataset and either this data needs to be transformed to normal or there's a more appropriate distribution to use for this data given that its minimum is 0.00.

This seems like it would be a common issue to solve in business analysis, but I haven't found any articles online describing this scenario. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

FWIW, here is the dataset for the current pay period I'm looking at:

2,173.67; 1,526.89;
1,325.96;
1,152.15;
1,013.83;
980.25;
887.76;
868.07;
811.69;
643.12;
589.70;
526.91;
378.00;
323.19;
255.75;
180.50; and
113.50

Comment: if you're excluding the zeros, one approach would be to take the log transform of your data, figure out the confidence intervals in logspace, then exponentiate the interval bounds (which guarantees positivity).

Comment: fyi these intervals will be asymmetric, which can make managers uncomfortable (but is necessary to avoid negative values).

Comment: Thanks, John. "Logspace" isn't something I'm familiar with. I could get up to speed on that, I suppose, as I certainly get what you're saying about doing a log transform (I just haven't ever done it). What I'm really looking for is a solution that I can implement in MS Excel so that this can be done automatically twice a month. Is that do-able?

Comment: ye friend, what I mean is, if your data are in A1:A10, take the log of those data and put them in B1:B10. Compute the confidence interval lower and upper bounds on the B1:B10 data, store those in C1:C2. Then, let D1:D2 be exp(D1:D2). Now D1:D2 are lower/upper bounds for a confidence interval on your data in A1:A10 which are guaranteed to be positive.

Comment: Thank you. Doing that now.

Comment: =exp(ln(a1)) = a1 ...in other words, there was never an issue with the original data being negative (see data set I provided in original post).

Comment: let's take this step by step. Can you compute a confidence interval on the logarithm of your data?

Comment: (above, I said "let D1:D2 be exp(D1:D2)", but that doesn't make sense, I meant "let D1:D2 be exp(C1:C2)").